# How to get social login buttons using devise + omniauth + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, omniauth

I am currently running a rails 4 application, and I would like to get social login buttons instead of links which are the default provided by omniauth / devise.

Currently I have a signup form which looks like this,

[image: current sign up form]

And I included, the following gems, `bootstrap-social-rails` and `font-awesome-rails`.

I am hoping to get some buttons that look like this,

[image: social login buttons]

My `new.html.erb` looks like the following,

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= f.submit "Twitter", class: "btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter fa fa-twitter"%>
    <%= f.submit "Sign in with Twitter", class: "btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter fa fa-twitter" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmniAuth authorisation performs by redirection to the provider service, which means that buttons are `<a href="...">`, not actual `<button>` tags.

In that case, what you would like to implement can be done like this:

```
<%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter), class: "btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter" do %>
   <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Sign in with Twitter
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need `_link.html.erb` file. There will be code for providers as i write below.

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %> 
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    .........
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Change this code to following code of line.

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "<i class='#{ICONS[provider]}'></i>".html_safe, omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "ui #{COLOR[provider]} mini submit button ok" %>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

And in initialize, make `CONSTANT` for icon and color.

```
ICONS = { google_oauth2: 'google plus', twitter: 'twitter', facebook: 'facebook', linkedin: 'linkedin', github: 'github'}
COLOR = { google_oauth2: 'blue', twitter: 'twitter', facebook: 'facebook', linkedin: 'linkedin', github: 'black' }
```

Please change the class name(if it is different, That is just demo classes not from bootstrap).

Comment: What file would I initialize the constants in?

Comment: The ICON and COLOR should be in fertilizer(file).

Comment: The `fertilizer` file?  This is a rails 4.2.5 app.